# Acceptable locations for junction boxes in a kitchen

Tags: wiring, junction-box

I'm trying to do some wiring in a kitchen with a that's somewhat below grade with a slab floor and another floor above it.  I'm going to need some junction boxes for the wiring.  Usually I see these in an attic or basement, but these locations aren't an option here.  Would it be okay to put them in the cabinets?  Behind stove?  Behind a refrigerator?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any of those should be fine.  The junction box has to remain accessible - that means you can't drywall over it or such but doesn't mean you can't park a major appliance in front of it.  Just put a blank cover plate over the box and call it good.

Answer (score 1):

All of these will be fine but the wires have to be protected.  Meaning in the walls or protected by armor if under cabinets.  I would shy away from under cabinets unless they are high as it is a favorite hiding spot for kids not to mention people tend to store big metal pans under cabinets and often just jam/throw them in there.